# Simulate Enter Key

Tags: vbscript

Is there a way to simulate the <kbd>enter</kbd> key in VBScript? Ex.:

```
set shl = createobject("wscript.shell")
shl.sendkeys "SIMULATED ENTER"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try `{ENTER}`, ie

```
shl.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

here's my reference http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/ezine/ezine120.htm

Answer (score 0):

The vbscript to press enter key working!

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

Comment: All Keys to press and their description: https://www.mediafire.com/file/ht33wetrwboplo6/PressAnyKey.png/file